# Scikit-learn LinearRegression: How to resolve the error " fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y' "?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, linear-regression

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.Linear_model import LinearRegression as lr
df = pd.DataFrame({"Match Score":[95,85,80,70,60], "Statistic score":[85,95,70,65,70]})
x =df[["Match Score"]]
y =df["Statistic score"]
lr.fit(x,y)
```

Error details:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-e644bf405118> in <module>
----> 1 lr.fit(x,y)

TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Comment: `lr().fit(x,y)`

Comment: Your `y` is missing the second set of square brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must instantiate the `LinearRegression` estimator first.

```
my_lr = lr().fit(x,y)
```

You also have a typo in your import statements, it's `sklearn.linear_model` with a small `l`.